# How to prevent re-render by unnecessary state change in zustand store?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, zustand

In zustand store, I have two variable, let's say varA, varB.
And I have other component K that depends on only varB, not varA.
But the problem is when the varA is set as new value in zustand store, my K component is re-rendered, and it produce undesirable result. How can I prevent this?

I tried useMemo, but it doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStore } from './my-zustand-store';

function K() {
  // I didn't even pull out varA from store.
  const varB = useStore((state) => state.varB);

  // Use useMemo to memoize varB
  const memoizedVarB = React.useMemo(() => varB, [varB]);
  
  console.log("re-rendering component K...");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Value of varB: {memoizedVarB}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default K;
```

The log is shown twice when I change varA.

Comment: which version of Zustand do you use?

Comment: Hi, @diesel94,  thank you.  I use ^4.3.8.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I read about the same problem on Zustand's GitHub issues in earlier versions and developers promised to fix that.. But who knows maybe it still exist.